# Are there any devices with open-source protocols over Wi-Fi?

Tags: smart-home, mqtt, hardware, coap, open-source

I know how to program **IoT using Arduino**; but I want some **ready made portable IoT devices** that do not need any programming at **device side**. Just I want to buy and add these devices to the network (after some configuration) and (by using documentation provided by company) write a controller logic to them.

**For Example:**

1. A ready made **MQTT thermostat** connect to some **broker and publish temperature** on some topic. Someone can buy that thermostat install it and read that temperature using **MQTT client**.
2. A ready made **CoAP regular light** that connect to some CoAP server, someone buy it replace his home lights with that and by sending some CoAP messages to that device using a CoAP client it can be turned ON/OFF.

Kindly share the **company name or links** (for REST/COAP/MQTT only), I tried searching and could not find anything except [Rachio Smart WiFi Sprinkler](http://www.rachio.com/) ([Docs](https://rachio.readme.io/docs/getting-started))

Answer (score 12):

The IKEA Trådfri lighting system is all CoAP based, you can find my write up on the protocol [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2017/04/02/tradfri-ikeas-new-smart-lighting-system/)

Belkin WeMo devices are all uPnP and SOAP controlled as well so another open/self describing protocol

Comment: Can we write a coap client to send a message to that? Further more i think it uses Zigbee

Comment: I've written a mqtt to coap bridge https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/tag/tradfri/ for the Ikea system. Yes bulbs use Zigbee, but if you read the link, you'll see the gateway uses CoAP